# Spacebar key ruins autocomplete when filtering for companies to include / exclude

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was using the filters to filter out a company as I start typing the company name I can see it in the list:

[image]

As I typed "United " the minute I hit a space and put an "S" to pick the right company the autocomplete disappears and all companies disappear, I end up with this:

[image]

Comment: That arrow looks more of a pink than red... and too perfect... and the rounded tail is pretty annoying.

Comment: also the shadow. Waaay to much effort!

Comment: Where is the freehand circle!

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed!

We (Andrew) switched from a [naive autocomplete feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) of Elasticsearch to a [more advanced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) (and accurate) one.

Thanks for your report!